# Are Christian Scientists against the regulation of antibiotics in agriculture?

Tags: christian-science

Governments around the world are heavily regulating the use of antibiotics in agriculture in an attempt to curb superbacteria. But Christian Scientists believe, as far as I understand it, that antibiotics do not really help because all diseases are psychosomatic. So, are they against such regulation? Do they believe that the egg industry should be allowed to use as much antibiotics as it wants to?

Comment: I have been unable to find any official Christian Science references specifically about the egg industry and the use of antibiotics or generally to do with agriculture and the use of antibiotics. What, might I ask, does this have to do with Christianity?

Comment: @Lesley Well, Christian Science is a branch of Christianity, isn't it? It just has a unique theology.

Comment: I agree that their theology is unique but just because a group of people self-identify as being Christian does not necessarily mean they are Christians. I hope to look into this tomorrow in order to find an answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may well be that Christian Scientists don’t believe that antibiotics can help to curb disease, but that may not have any bearing on whether they are against government regulation of antibiotics.  Here, in Europe, regulation has worked positively to reduce the use of antibiotics in poultry farming.

My search on official Christian Science web sites failed to find anything about the use of antibiotics in general or in chicken husbandry in particular.  However, I did find an old (1907) article on weeds: [an article](https://sentinel.christianscience.com/issues/1907/11/10-11/weeds)

> WEEDS: As the serious prevalence of weeds is an infallible indication of poor farming, so the abundance of undesirable thoughts is a never-failing sign of poor thinking; and conversely, the absence is a sure concomitant of good thinking.  No student of agriculture denies that scientific methods are needed to obtain the best results in farming, and it is [of] infinitely greater importance to understand and ***practise the Science of Mind in order to get rid of the evils which for so long a time have been permitted to grow in human consciousness***.

The Christian Science Monitor December 2023 issue had [this article](https://www.csmonitor.com/text_edition/Environment/2023/1201/In-a-return-to-forgotten-lands-young-farmers-go-small-demand-less) about a new generation of young farmers who are finding success with small agricultural projects that result in a more sustainable lifestyle:

> “There’s been a really kind of dramatic change in the way that farmers see what agriculture can do,” says Jules Pretty, professor of environment and society at the University of Essex in England. .. But the thing about regenerative practices – farming that rebuilds ecological health even as it harvests – is that they’re nearly impossible to do at a large scale. Industrial agriculture is built to go big. That means long rows of single crops that allow for high-tech automation and big farm equipment, ***chemical inputs like pesticides and synthetic fertilizers*** that increase yields, and economies of scale that keep prices low. .. ***Regenerative agriculture, on the other hand, attempts to rebuild ecosystems in a way that integrates the various plants, animals, and microbes that naturally exist in a specific place.***

With regard to what’s going on in the U.S. with the regulation of antibiotics in poultry farming, [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antibiotic_use_in_the_United_States_poultry_farming_industry) says:

> In recent times, antibiotic use in poultry production has become a subject of debate because of concerns about bacterial antibiotic resistance.

It is noteworthy that antibiotics can migrate into and accumulate in the egg of the chicken being treated.  Antibiotics are also fed to cattle.  Regulation that results in controlling the use of additives (such as pesticides and antibiotics) must be a good thing.

**Conclusion:** I can only assume that Christian Scientists will continue to use natural and non-invasive farming techniques whether in agriculture or in poultry farming.

Answer (score -1):

Antibiotics themselves aren't connected with any Christian prohibition (unlike blood for example), but too big usage of them may hurt peoples' health. In this way we are for reducing antibiotics.

Comment: Hello! The question is asking for answers from the perspective of the Church of Christ, Scientist (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_Christ,_Scientist), also known as Christian Science, while your answer appears to be from a general Christian perspective. Do you have a source specifically for what Christian Science teaches on this issue?